# In order to inject dependencies into an object, i must first inject it into the right component?

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

So if I have a class in which i would like to inject some objects then first i have to get an application context somehow and inject this object into the component stored by the main application class?

Comment: Your question is too vague and broad right now. Please add more context to it and at concrete code examples.

Comment: I think I see where you are going with the question but how about providing some code so we can see for sure without making assumptions?

Comment: i still don't understand fully the mechanics of di with dagger, so i should learn more about it first, but thanks for your answer.

Comment: what causes my confusion is that i don't see what makes a class qualified to have injected members. when i was playing with dagger (1) i kinda got the object graph functionality, but still had issues. this component/module stuff is harder to understand.